# Connecting Cloud Run Node app to Cloud SQL using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a Nodejs app on `Google Cloud Run` which is supposed to connect to the `Cloud SQL` MySQL database using `Sequelize` ORM.

It works fine if I use the local proxy for the cloud sql instance, but when I try to deploy it to Cloud Run, Sequelize is not able to find the db instance.

I tried giving '/cloudsql/' in the host property of sequelize, tried the public IP (it times out every time)

This is what my config looks like:

```
exports.PRODUCTION = {
    HOST: "/cloudsql/<connection-name-here>",
    USER: "<db-user",
    PASSWORD: "<db-password>",
    DB: "<db-name>",
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
};
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. Only to be sure we are in the same page, you have followed all instructions in [Quickstart for Cloud SQL using Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-connect-run) like creating the connection and the SA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. I was passing the UNIX socket path in the host property (facepalm)

You have to pass the socket path in the socketPath property in dialectOptions in the config.